# Installling rbokeh from github trouble

Tags: r, github, devtools

I am having a lot of trouble downloading packages from github. I think my problem is that I don't have an up-to-date R version. If I do that then I think I can download packages from github. Anyone have any idea how to update my R Version so that it will allow me to do this? Or possibly is it a different issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Nicholas/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/devtools_1.8.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 339399 bytes (331 KB)
downloaded 331 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqYKiyz\downloaded_packages
> library(devtools)
Warning message:
package ‘devtools’ was built under R version 3.2.1 
> devtools::install_github("ramnathv/htmlwidgets")
Downloading github repo ramnathv/htmlwidgets@master
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘stringi’

> devtools::install_github("bokeh/rbokeh")
Downloading github repo bokeh/rbokeh@master
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘stringi’
```

Comment: `install.packages("stringi")` ?

Comment: Install stringi package.

Comment: `devtools::install_github("GITHUB/REPO", dependencies=TRUE)`